# AVCaptureDevice.Position = AVCaptureDevice.Position.Type

Tags: swift, xcode

I am using the `AVCaptureDevice.Position` command for a function that takes `AVCaptureDevice.Position` as one of its parameters. For some reason I am getting the error

> Cannot convert value of type 'AVCaptureDevice.Position.Type' to expected argument type 'AVCaptureDevice.Position'

I am not sure why I am getting this error, but here is me calling the function and I will also include the code of the function:

```
let visionImage = VisionImage(buffer: sampleBuffer)
visionImage.orientation = imageOrientation(deviceOrientation: UIDevice.current.orientation, cameraPosition: AVCaptureDevice.Position)
```

Here is the code for my function:

```
func imageOrientation(
      deviceOrientation: UIDeviceOrientation,
      cameraPosition: AVCaptureDevice.Position
    ) -> UIImage.Orientation {
      switch deviceOrientation {
      case .portrait:
        return cameraPosition == .front ? .leftMirrored : .right
      case .landscapeLeft:
        return cameraPosition == .front ? .downMirrored : .up
      case .portraitUpsideDown:
        return cameraPosition == .front ? .rightMirrored : .left
      case .landscapeRight:
        return cameraPosition == .front ? .upMirrored : .down
      case .faceDown, .faceUp, .unknown:
        return .up
      }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have `..... , cameraPosition: AVCaptureDevice.Position)` you are supplying a type to the `cameraPosition` parameter. Shouldn’t it be an instance of that type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AVCaptureDevice.Position` is an *enum* https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/position

Set .front, .back or .unspecified:

```
visionImage.orientation = imageOrientation(deviceOrientation: UIDevice.current.orientation, cameraPosition: AVCaptureDevice.Position.back)
```